# FluxCD: create repository failed, unable to unmarshall repository json: unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: kubernetes, bitbucket, fluxcd

I'm trying to do

```
flux bootstrap bitbucket-server \                                                                                                                  ✱
  --token-auth \
  --hostname=bitbucket.org \
  --owner=akhateeb \
  --username=akhateeb22 \
  --repository=flux-fleet \
  --branch=main \
  --path=apps \
  --personal true
```

but I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Any idea what does this error mean and how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue just now. Bitbucket repositories that are in "bitbucket.org" are labelled as so-called "Bitbucket Cloud" so will not be same as ones in a "bitbucket server" which is meant to be "on-prem" server.
As per discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2/discussions/2338) need to use "generic git" command from [here](https://fluxcd.io/flux/cmd/flux_bootstrap_git/) for Bitbucket cloud.